# Why are unity builds faster given modern compilers?

Tags: c++, builds, build-system

Consider (using Visual C++ as an example):

```
cl /EHsc a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
```

versus

```
cat a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp > unity.cpp
cl /EHsc unity.cpp
```

Why is the first variant slower given a modern compiler? I've seen people say that unity builds avoid headers being parsed multiple times. But then why doesn't a modern compiler cache its header parse results and reuse them between compilation units? Well, they already do. That's what precompiled headers are. But then why not do it automatically for everything all the time? You might say that the order of includes, undefs, and other weird shit can matter, but that's the pathological/exceptional case. You could still detect a well behaved header file and cache it, could you not?

Comment: add the `/showIncludes ` flag and compare how many times a file gets loaded. Even the most basic standard header will have a massive include list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most C and C++ header files (notably system headers, or those of large C++ libraries like [Qt](http://qt.io/)) have [`#include` guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or the non-standard [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once). Practically speaking, standard C++ headers like `<set>` or `<map>` are often expanded to at least ten thousand lines each.

So when some [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (like your `unity.cpp`) is including some given one header file `foo.h` several times, it gets included only once (the first occurrence of its `#include`).

Hence, the preprocessed form of `unity.cpp` is *shorter* (in preprocessed tokens) than the sum of the preprocessed form of each of `a.cpp`, `b.cpp`, `c.cpp`.

And you could check that by getting their preprocessed form. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)  you would use (perhaps adding other [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) like `-I`... to add an include directory, `-D`... to define a preprocessor symbol, `-H` to get the included files' path, ...)

```
g++ -C -E a.cpp > a.ii
g++ -C -E b.cpp > b.ii
g++ -C -E c.cpp > c.ii
g++ -C -E unity.cpp > unity.ii
```

and you could compare the cumulated word count obtained by `wc a.ii b.ii c.ii` with the one of `wc unity.ii`

<sup>(I leave you to adapt these Linux commands to your `cl` compiler & Windows)</sup>

However, having several translation units enable parallel builds (in several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running simultaneously), e.g. with [`make -j`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html).

(Hence, in practical terms, you may want some trade-off; I've got the habit of having `*.cc` files of a few thousand lines)

> You might say that the order of includes, undefs, and other weird shit can matter, but that's the pathological/exceptional case.

I am not sure it is pathological. On Linux, I would presume it could be quite common. See [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

> You could still detect a well behaved header file and cache it

In practice, that does not work well. Within GCC, some clever people worked on preparsed headers [without success](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108). Future C++ standards might define [modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules) (See also Clang documentation [on them](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html))

<sup>NB: I am answering with a Linux & GCC -centric view, but you could adapt my answer to your Visual C++ & Windows (which I don't know) because it is much more a language (and practical) issue than an operating system & compiler one.</sup>